# How can I use a Slack Bot to get a list of all messages send by itself?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack bot with a bot token and I want to use it to look for a previous message it has sent.

I originally tried to do something like

```
res = sc.api_call(
    "conversations.history",
    channel = channel_id,
    limit = 100,
    oldest = time.time() - 60*60*24
)
```

and then my plan was to search through that, but I need the `channels:history` scope, and I don't want to use the oauth flow for this.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I was using the same token for reading and writing. I'm not sure what the difference is, but I need to use the "Bot User OAuth Access Token" for posting on behalf of the bot, and "OAuth Access Token" for performing the actions that required the scopes, such as `channels:history` (which I added as a scope before)

Comment: No, that is not the correct answer. you can use `channels.history` with both your bot and access token, as long as you have the correct scope. So there must be something else going on here in my opinion.